# my laravel app generating error in shared hosting

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, cpanel

i deployed my laravel app to a shared hosting and i got this error

```
file_put_contents(C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel Projects\bank\iscbank\storage\framework/sessions/qM5STFvAXNcmpuJkllutrtS1PumOi0OXhG7TdNwL): failed to open stream: No such file or directory
```

i followed all the instructions on how to install laravel app in cpanel.
I dont know if its because i ran these commmands before zipping the project

```
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan config:clear
```

i dont know whats wrong or what i did wrong

Comment: did you run composer install ?

Comment: yes i ran it on my localhost before uploading it

Comment: what if you run it from your server ?

Comment: also , maybe you need to chmod 777 -R storage folder. and i think it can also chown www-data:www-data

Comment: how, its a shared hosting

Comment: what do you mean by shared hosting ? a remote server is that true ?

Comment: yes i mean it hosted on cpanel

Comment: run composer there , what is the problem here ?

Comment: i dont have access to shell or terminal

Comment: to resolve that you have to get access there, because , it seems a premission problem . so  you need to get in

Comment: ok then you have to give full access to storage folder and also do `cache:clear` and `config:clear` i know you are on shored hosting but you can do this programatically artisan command https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/artisan#programmatically-executing-commands clear:cache because laravel looking for xamp folder you can check this too because its putting content on xamp folder

Comment: Remove files from `bootstrap/cache` folder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do these

1. Remove files from `bootstrap/cache` folder
2. Remove all the files/folder inside from these 
   `storage/framework/cache`,
   `storage/framework/sessions`,
   `storage/framework/views`

and try